# Are class arguments stored after function execution?

Tags: c++, class, memory-management

I am brand new to C++ and trying to better how understand memory is allocated and stored in class methods.

Lets say I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ExampleClass {

    public:

        void SetStoredAttribute(int Argument);
        int GetStoredAttribute(void);

    private:

        int StoredAttribute;
};


void ExampleClass::SetStoredAttribute(int Argument) {
    StoredAttribute = Argument;
};


int ExampleClass::GetStoredAttribute(void) {
    return StoredAttribute;
};


int main() {

    ExampleClass Object;
    Object.SetStoredAttribute(1);
    cout << Object.GetStoredAttribute();

    return 0;
};
```

What does C++ do with the argument once my *SetStoredAttribute* method is finished? Does it free that memory or do I need to do this manually?

Comment: If there wasn't a class involved - if `StoredAttribute` was a global variable and `SetStoredAttribute` was not part of a class - would you know the answer?

Comment: @user253751 Okay yeah, I’m coming from python so moving on to C++, I know memory management is really important. I just wasn’t too sure if namespaces and scopes actually dealt with the memory after use or if it just hid it from outside of the scope. Thanks!

Comment: Yes the variable `StoredAttribute` is retained, With that said your class lacks a constructor that initializes `StoredAttribute ` so that if you forgot to call `SetStoredAttribute()` but called `GetStoredAttribute()` you would have undefined behavior because the value of `StoredAttribute` was not initialized in that case.

Comment: @drescherjm So if I called GetStoredAttribute, without calling SetStoredAttribute, would StoredAttribute return as null or would it fail to compile altogether?

Comment: It won't return null, typically you will get a random garbage value but this is considered undefined behavior meaning your code is broken and any thing can happen. The compiler may warn you at compile time and some may warn you in the debugger but by the language standard nothing is required by the compiler  to prevent UB.  Related: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: @TylerBeaird What the compiler does in C++ about memory allocation is basically that it packs variables together into bigger variables or essentially "memory chunks". An ExampleClass instance is (probably in this case) just 4 bytes, `main`'s local variables are one ExampleClass, which is (probably in this case) 4 bytes. The compiler keeps track of info like "StoredAttribute is the first 4 bytes of an ExampleClass" and "ExampleClass is the first 4 bytes of main's local variables" and you only deal with allocating or deallocating the outer, big blocks of memory.

Comment: Local variables are allocated/deallocated when the function is called/when it returns. You could also imagine a `class Example2 {ExampleClass stuff[100];};`, and then if you wanted to allocate an Example2 on the heap with `new Example2` (which allocates 400 bytes), you wouldn't also have to allocate `stuff` separately, or 100 ExampleClass instances, because they are just names for sections of those 400 bytes that are already allocated... hope that helps and isn't confusing. There are better tutorials out there than me.

Comment: @user253751 No that makes sense, very helpful to know that scoped data is stored in chunks and that memory is allocated in a sort of hierarchical fashion. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function arguments, including those in member functions, always have [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). They start to exist at the beginning of the function scope, and cease to exist at the end of the function scope, and the implementation deals with ensuring they are "allocated" and "deallocated".

On most platforms, this is implemented in two ways.

- Firstly by a stack, often called **The Stack**, because it is unique to the thread of execution, with a special purpose register in the CPU pointing to the top.
- Secondly, the arguments are directly assigned to registers in the CPU.